# Склонение аббревиатур

Tags: склонение, аббревиатуры

Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняются ли такие аббревиатуры, как *ООН, ВВС, АТС, ЮАР, НОТ*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не склоняются.

ООН, ЮАР — аббревиатуры, оканчивающиеся  словами женского рода (нация, республика);

АТС, ВВС — буквенные инициальные аббревиатуры;

Не склоняются:

1. Аббревиатуры, которые заканчиваются гласной. Например, ООО, ОАО, МГУ.
2. Аббревиатуры, заканчивающиеся словами женского и среднего рода. Например, АЗС — Автоматическая Заправочная Станция (женский род).
3. Аббревиатуры буквенного характера. Например, ФСБ, СНГ, СССР.
4. Аббревиатуры, в которых имеется целиком форма косвенного падежа: завкафедрой, минобороны.
5. Заимствованные инициальные аббревиатуры (непереводные), оканчивающиеся на твёрдый согласный (ЮНИСЕФ, ЦЕРН).

Аббревиатура склоняется:

а) если заканчивается словом мужского рода. Например, МХАТ — последнее слово театр мужского рода.

б) частично сокращённые с последним словом — существительным мужского или женского рода в именительном падеже единственного числа (Росконцерт);

в) сокращение одного слова (пригласите всех замов);

г) слоговые аббревиатуры, оканчивающиеся на твёрдый согласный, с последним компонентом -бат, -ком, -рук, -торг, -фак и т. п. (на филфаке, с худруком).

Сокращенные наименования чаще выступают в роли неизменяемых слов. Но варианты склонения все же допустимы. Склонение этих слов зависит от того, на какую букву они заканчиваются.
Если последняя буква в аббревиатуре гласная, слово нельзя изменять: *Руководство ФИФА выбрало новое место проведения чемпионата.* В такой ситуации склонение приведет к искажению смысла.

Другой вариант, когда сложносокращенное слово заканчивается на одну или несколько согласных. Тогда к аббревиатуре может добавляться окончание, которое прописывается строчными буквами. Например: *Сотрудники ЗАГСа придумали для молодоженов новую акцию. Продукция соответствует ГОСТу.* Такие случаи единичны. Лучше избегать склонения сокращений.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь грамматических вариантов русского языка» Л. К. Граудиной, В. А. Ицковича и Л. П. Катлинской (М., 2008) рекомендует склонять аббревиатуры ВАК, ГОСТ, МХАТ, ВГИК, ТЮЗ, СПИД, ОМОН. Прочие аббревиатуры в строгой деловой письменной речи не склоняются. В разговорной речи склонение возможно: пробка на МКАДе, сотрудник ЗАГСа. Грамота.ру.